# Existence of a smooth frame for a vector bundle

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $p:E\rightarrow M$ be a smooth n dimensional bundle and $M$ a smooth manifold. My question is does there always exist a local frame for this vector bundle. A local frame is a collection of smooth sections $r_1,...,r_n:U\rightarrow E$ such that $r_1(m),...,r_n(m) $ is a basis for $p^{-1}(m)$. If such a frame exist how can we find it? Thank you!

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that your bundle is locally trivial.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can you elaborate further please? I don't get how it follows immediately

Comment: Can you find the frame you want if $E$ is a trivial bundle, so that $E=M\times\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes using the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by defining a set of functions from $s_i:M\rightarrow M\times \mathbb{R}^n$. I kind of see how local triviality can be used to define a frame but I still cannot figure out how exactly to do it

Comment: Well, a general vector bundle is locally trivial, so you can do **exactly** the same thing locally. I suggest you think about tthis for a while. I for one will not tell you — i is better for you to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think I have enough to work on. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $\phi:p^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ be a local trivialization and $\{e_1,...,e_k\}$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Define $r_i:U\to E$ by $r_i(p):=\phi^{-1}(p,e_i)$ for all $p\in U$. Then $\{r_1,...,r_k\}$ is the desired frame.